# Since when are natural deduction proofs allowed to terminate with undischarged assumptions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

So far I thought natural deduction proofs are NOT allowed to terminate with undischarged assumptions. However this seems to be what's happening here:

[image]

When I translate this Gentzen style proof into a Fitch style proof I get this:

[image]

As clearly visible in the Fitch style proof the proof ends without discharging assumptions $[B]$ and $[A]$.

However I don't think the author of the Gentzen style proof made a mistake, which makes me question my understanding of things so far. Can you help me clear up where I am going wrong?

The screenshot of the Gentzen style proof is from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOiZatlZtGU) recording of a presentation on type theory.

Comment: The proof does look unfinished. Discharging the assumptions on lines 6 and 7, you would end up with $B\implies [A \implies A \land B].$

Comment: I know, that is my point.

Comment: Sometimes I have left proofs unfinished for readability, e.g. if I start a formal proof with Peano axioms (introducing N, S, 0)  as 5 separate assumptions. For readability, I would usually not discharge those assumptions.

Comment: You have a theorem (or tautology) on line 5 since all previous assumptions were discharged. Line 9 is not a theorem (or tautology) since the assumptions on lines 6 and 7 have not been discharged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gentzen proof *does* discharge the $B \land A$ with the $\rightarrow \ I$, but indeed does not discharge the $B$ and the $A$.

So, it proves (in a very clumsy way) the sequent $B, A \vdash A \land B$.

Translated into a Fitch style proof, it has $B$ and $A$ as premises, and $A \land B$ as the conclusion:

[image]

Gentzen proofs without any undischarged assumptions would be proofs or arguments without any premises, and thus of stand-alone valid sentences.

Comment: Okay, I see, thanks.

Comment: @CarlMummert Oh shoot, yes, they *do* discharge the $B \land A$!  I'll update, thanks!

Comment: Is the Fitch proof you wrote in your edit different from mine? The nesting of the assumptions is different, but that makes no difference in this case, does it?

Comment: @user3578468 Aside from the fact that in my proof the $B \land A$ gets discharged, whereas in yours it does not (and that's because your line 4 does not follow the typical format of the $\rightarrow \ I$ rule), you could indeed say that they are similar: your proof, like the Gentzen proof, simply introduces assumptions at later points, while my proof introduces all assumptions at the same time. Indeed, we can look at your proof as a 'finished' proof as long as we are careful to state that what it proofs is that the last line is a consequence of all the assumptions still in place at that time.

Comment: I think you mean "stand-alone valid tautologies" not sentences necessarily.  Although then standalone and valid might be redundant.

Comment: @Bram28 "Gentzen proofs without any undischarged assumptions would be proofs or arguments without any premises"
Do you also consider premises to be assumptions? Typically in a proof I don' t discharge the premises. So a proof that discharges the assumptions could still have premises remaining. A proof that is 'premise-less' after discharging the assumptions would be a tautology.

Comment: @john Correct: premises would work just like assumptions ... but end up being assumptions that never get discharged.